# Markov Chains: Finding the Embedded DTMC $P(t)$ from generator matrix $Q$

Tags: probability, matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Markov Chains: Finding the Embedded DTMC (transition probability matrix) $P(t)$ from generator matrix $Q$ where the sample space $S=(0,1,2)$
>
> $Q=\begin{pmatrix}
>         -4 & 2 & 2 \\
>         3 & -5 & 2 \\
>         0 & 3 & -3 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}$

I found the forward Kolmogorov equations to be:

$$p'_{00}(t)=-4p_{00}(t)+3p_{01}(t)$$
$$p'_{01}(t)=2p_{10}(t)-5p_{11}(t)+3p_{12}(t)$$
$$p'_{02}(t)=2p_{20}(t)+2p_{21}(t)-3p_{21}(t)$$

Also I solved for the stationary probability to get:
$$(\pi_0 , \pi_1 , \pi_2 )=(9/35, 12/35 , 14/35)$$

I think I'm supposed to find $e^{Qt}$ in which case I'll need to diagonalise a $3\times 3$ which I'm not sure I can do or somehow integrate the equations.

Comment: It is not clear what you actually want to determine. Is it the matrix of transition probability functions $P(t) = [p_{i,j}(t)]_{i,j = 0,1,2}$, where $p_{i,j}(t) := \mathbb{P}(X(t) = j \mid X(0) = i)$, or is the matrix of transition probabilities $P = [p_{i,j}]_{i,j = 0,1,2}$, where $p_{i,j}$ is the probability that the process jumps to state $j$ given that the process currently is in state $i$ and a jump occurs?

Comment: @Ritz it's the second, - transition probability matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transition probabilities $p_{i,j}$ are given by

\begin{equation}
p_{i,j} = \frac{q_{i,j}}{-q_{i,i}}, \quad i \neq j
\end{equation}

and $0$ otherwise, with $q_{i,j}$ the entry in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column of the transition rate matrix $Q$ (numbering of rows and columns starts at $0$ in this case). See the $s_{i,j}$ at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain#Embedded_Markov_chain). The interpretation of $p_{i,j}$ is the probability that the process jumps to state $j$ given that the process is currently in state $i$ and a jump occurs.

---

Entirely unrelated, but the Kolmogorov forward equations that you have derived are incorrect. Define $p_{i,j}(t) := \mathbb{P}(X(t) = j \mid X(0) = i)$ and let $S$ be the state space of the continuous time Markov chain. Then the Kolmogorov forward equations are

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} p_{i,j}(t) = \sum_{k \in S} p_{i,k}(t) q_{k,j}.
\end{equation}

In your case the Kolmogorov forward equations for $i = 0$ are

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} p_{0,0}(t) &= -4 p_{0,0}(t) + 3 p_{0,1}(t), \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} p_{0,1}(t) &= 2 p_{0,0}(t) - 5 p_{0,1}(t) + 3 p_{0,2}(t), \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} p_{0,2}(t) &= 2 p_{0,0}(t) + 2 p_{0,1}(t) - 3 p_{0,2}(t).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot :) On a side note, why will the $g_i$ - the expected time/steps to reach $x$ if we start from $i$ different for $P(t)$ and $Q$? but the $h_i$ - the probability of reaching one set before another is the same for $Q$ and $P(t)$?

Comment: $P(t)$ does not mean what you think it means. I think you are asking about the difference between a discrete-time Markov chain (DTMC) and a continuous-time Markov chain (CTMC). In a DTMC the time spent in a state is always 1 time unit. In a CTMC the time spent in a state has an exponential distribution with a parameter that depends on the state. So, the expected time to go from state $i$ to state $j$ is different for the DTMC and CTMC. The transition behavior is exactly the same for both, so the probability to reach a certain set of states before another is the same in both cases.

Comment: Isn't $P(t)$ the embedded DTMC? I thought $Q$ was the generator of the CTMC. Now it seems like $P(t)$ contains probabilities of jumps at certain times $\rightarrow$ it's a CTMC

Comment: So to find $g_i$'s of the $P(t)$ will I need to use $g_i=1+ \sum_{j\in S} p_{ij}g_j$?

Comment: $P(t)$ is a matrix with entries $p_{i,j}(t) := \mathbb{P}(X(t) = j \mid X(0) = i)$. In words: $p_{i,j}(t)$ is the probability that the Markov chain is in state $j$ at time $t$ given that the Markov chain started in state $i$ at time $0$. $Q$ is indeed the infinitesimal generator of a CTMC. $Q$ is also called the transition rate matrix. Analogously, $P$ is the transition probability matrix of a DTMC. So, what $P$ (**not** $P(t)$) is for the DTMC, $Q$ is for the CTMC.

Comment: About the $g_i$, you should ask a new question.

Comment: I posted it here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690189/dtmc-and-cmtc-first-passage-probabilities-and-expectation , if you get a chance to look at it